# Installing Previous Firmware in iPhone | New Firmware keeps Rebooting iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, restore, firmware

After upgrading to iOS 14.4.2 my iphone keeps rebooting every 5 mins! I would like to restore my iphone to iOS 14.3.7. After finding signed firmware I tried using iTunes but kept getting error 9 . I found the solution in [iFixit where Barry's answers](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/97653/How+to+fix+iTunes+error+9#:%7E:text=Error%209%20is%20almost%20always,are%20trying%20to%20restore%20with) stated that (in short) this is Apples way of giving trouble by removing signed firmware! However he suggested a solution that utilizes paid version of the software to flash earlier version of firmware (ISPW) into iphone, using **Reiboot**

Now my iphone is completely unlocked, with my account signed in and everything is legit, yet if I restore earlier ISPW, then iTunes keep giving me error that I cant install old firmware! I need to know if there are any free tools online or Github project that can flash old firmware into iPhone? or anyway to check what is causing kernel panic.

When I say old firmware i mean just one step earlier revision where my iphone didnt keep rebooting!

---

(update 1) iOS 14.4.2 is known to have heating issue which is perhaps why my iphone is rebooting - [source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660693)

Comment: Have you tried iOS 14.4.2?

Comment: @lhf sorry correction, the current is indeed 14.4.2. yet it keeps restarting my iphone when idle soo annoying. However when i use the phone like browsing internet or make calls, it doesnt restart! it only restarts when sitting idle.

Answer (score -1):

If I have to be honest (and it’s really neat that you are doing this), you probably shouldn’t install previous firmware. It’s probably rebooting for a reason. There might be some broken blocks or code. It could also be infected, possibly malware or an app that uses your device for Crypto Mining. It could also be your device. Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: What is the solution if I dont install previous firmware? I have already resetted complete settings and files, the phone has no apps installed now and still it is heating and rebooting.

Comment: i had whatsapp, instagram and other social media apps installed previously and i am not sure if they would install crypto mining malware! I heard some torrent platforms install hidden crypto malware but I never had anything of that type installed in my iphone before resetting the phone.

Comment: I do have a question- why don’t you want latest? Apple doesn’t sign any other IPSWs than current ones. If it keeps getting hot, either something is REALLY wrong with your phone, or it’s been hacked. iPhones can usually heat up when they are charging, so try charging it up all the way, then installing the firmware.

Comment: i dont know if its hacked or not. but i did reset to factory which means removed all data as well. But still heating.